# remove character from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like following

```
d = {'MNDTHNFEYH': ' 7.4775763897997019', 'MNDTNNTEYS': ' 7.6740344272610006', 
     "  ['MAPTNNTEYH": '[7.2142815502006803', 'MFPTNNTEYS': ' 7.5108109773494114',
     'MFDTHNAEYH': ' 7.6695035046773761'}
```

In this dictionary, I tried to remove `[`,but I'm not getting it.So that it should look like

```
d = {'MNDTHNFEYH': ' 7.4775763897997019', 'MNDTNNTEYS': ' 7.6740344272610006', 
     'MAPTNNTEYH': ' 7.2142815502006803', 'MFPTNNTEYS': ' 7.5108109773494114',
     'MFDTHNAEYH': ' 7.6695035046773761'}
```

Please help me.

Comment: your desired output removes more than just `[`.  It also removes some quotes and spaces in the keys (but not values)...

Answer (score 2):

```
{k.translate(None,'''[ '"'''):v.translate(None,'[') for k,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: I'd say put it in a function and have it reusable to strip more than just '[' and ']'.

Comment: @SuperDisk -- sure ... I'm still not exactly sure what OP wants ... so it's hard to give a complete answer rigjt off tje bad ...

Comment: err... That was supposed to say "the bat"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only have alphabets in your key and float in values you can use regex to eliminate every other char

```
import re
d = {'MNDTHNFEYH': ' 7.4775763897997019', 'MNDTNNTEYS': ' 7.6740344272610006', "   ['MAPTNNTEYH": '[7.2142815502006803', 'MFPTNNTEYS': ' 7.5108109773494114', 'MFDTHNAEYH': ' 7.6695035046773761'}
# In the key replace everything else that is not in A-Z with ''
# In value replace everything else that is not in 0-9 or . with ''
d = {re.sub(r'[^A-Z]+','',k):re.sub(r'[^0-9.]+','',v) for k,v in d.items()}
d
{'MAPTNNTEYH': '7.2142815502006803',
 'MFDTHNAEYH': '7.6695035046773761',
 'MFPTNNTEYS': '7.5108109773494114',
 'MNDTHNFEYH': '7.4775763897997019',
 'MNDTNNTEYS': '7.6740344272610006'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want to strip out the characters "[ " from the key and value prefix. str.lstrip does the job for you. You only need to iterate through your dictionary and strip the characters from your key and value while regenerating the dictionary through dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> d={'MNDTHNFEYH': ' 7.4775763897997019', 'MNDTNNTEYS': ' 7.6740344272610006', "   ['MAPTNNTEYH": '[7.2142815502006803', 'MFPTNNTEYS': ' 7.5108109773494114', 'MFDTHNAEYH': ' 7.6695035046773761'}
>>> d = {k.strip(" [\"\'"): v.strip(" [\"\'") for k, v in d.items()}
>>> import pprint
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
>>> pp.pprint(d)
{   'MAPTNNTEYH': '7.2142815502006803',
    'MFDTHNAEYH': '7.6695035046773761',
    'MFPTNNTEYS': '7.5108109773494114',
    'MNDTHNFEYH': '7.4775763897997019',
    'MNDTNNTEYS': '7.6740344272610006'}
```

If you are not using Py2.7+, you can just pass the generator construct to the inbuilt `dict`

```
>>> d = dict(k.lstrip(" [\"\'"): v.lstrip(" [\"\'") for k, v in d.items())
```